# partial parallel and serial compilation with make

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

I am compiling `llvm` with `make`. When I do a parallel compile I do not have enough RAM during the linking steps. Is it possible to to a parallel compilation for all the object files and serial compilation during the linking step? For now stop compilation when my machine starts swapping and just restart the build process with `make -j1`, it would be neat if this could be done without human interaction.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Make avoids building things in parallel by declaring dependency relationships for them.  One assumes that you cannot start the linking of object files until after they're built, so make should already be avoiding linking until the object files are available...?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any `make` implementation that dynamically adapts the degree of parallelism according to resource consumption.  Indeed, although there is a potential to do that to some degree, the problem is not really solvable by `make`, because processes' resource consumption is not static.  That is, a `make` could conceivably observe, say, that physical RAM was overcommitted, and react by holding off on starting new child processes, but it cannot easily protect against starting several child processes while resource consumption is low, which then balloon to demand more resources than are available.

However, depending on the makefile, there may be a workaround: you can name specific targets for `make` to build.  You can use that to specify what targets you want to build in parallel, and then run a separate `make` to complete the build serially.  That might look something like this:

```
make -j4 object1.o object2.o object3.o object4.o
make
```

That's rather unwieldy though.  Supposing that there exists a target (or that you can create one) that represents all the object files but not any of the linked libraries / executables, then you can use that:

**Makefile**

```
OBJECTS = object1.o object2.o object3.o object4.o

all: my_program

my_program: objects
        # ...

# This target collects all the objects:
objects: $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all objects
```

**Command line**

```
make -j4 objects
make
```

Comment: thanks, I suspected that this was not possible with `make` but hoped someone would come up with some clever workaround. Sadly, the described way is much more complicated that just stopping make when it starts swapping.

Comment: This *is* the workaround, @gdkrmr.  I don't think it's particularly complicated, myself, and it has the advantage of doing the job as desired without manual intervention.  But if you prefer your present technique then by all means, continue to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your memory consumption correlates somehow with the load, you may limit `make` to take load into account with `-l` option. Relevant [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel):

> When the system is heavily loaded, you will probably want to run fewer jobs than when it is lightly loaded. You can use the ‘-l’ option to tell make to limit the number of jobs to run at once, based on the load average. The ‘-l’ or ‘--max-load’ option is followed by a floating-point number.

This might or might not help in your case, but it can be worth to check.

Comment: that sounds really interesting, never checked what happens to load if the system is swapping.